# Deploying two Django apps on a single domain with Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, deployment, mezzanine

I'm a newbie when it comes to deployment and need some help/advice on what to do here. I've searched around but the answers out there left me more confused.

I currently have two Django apps deployed on Heroku that I will have to move under a single domain (www.example.com).

- App 1: Mezzanine website with separate DB - shown when users visit www.example.com
- App 2: Django application with separate DB - shown when users visit www.example.com/app

Is it possible/recommended to do this on Heroku or would I have to "combine" both App 1 and App 2 as a single app on Heroku? Or is this a matter of configuring my DNS? I've already configure my domain to point to one heroku app, but not sure how to do two. Has anyone done something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perfect article about it.
http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/10/29/serving-multiple-django-applications-with-nginx-gunicorn-supervisor/